# I am curious about the cause of this exception: color1.R - color2.R resulting in overflow

Tags: vb.net

This operation throws an exception: "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."

```
fromColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
toColor = Drawing.Color.Red
Dim test1 As Integer = (toColor.G - fromColor.G)
```

...although G is 0 and 255 respectivelly, so it looks like a simple "0-255". `color.G` is a byte.

This operation works just fine:

```
fromColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
toColor = Drawing.Color.Red
Dim test2 As Integer = (CInt(toColor.G) - CInt(fromColor.G))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Color.G`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.g(v=vs.110).aspx) is a [byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte(v=vs.110).aspx), so your code is similar to:

```
Dim num1 As Byte = 0
Dim num2 As Byte = 255
Dim num3 As Byte = num1 - num2  ' -255 '
```

So you are subtracting two [bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2ayt412.aspx) from each other, the result is also a byte. But in this case a negative byte which is invalid. The valid range is from 0 to 255.

That explains also why casting them to `Int32` will not cause the overflow because then the result will also be an `Integer`.

It's sufficient to cast one of both to integer:

```
Dim test1 As Integer = toColor.G - CInt(fromColor.G)
```

Here is the documentation:

[- Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh10hha2.aspx):

> The result data type is a numeric type appropriate for the data types
>   of expression1 and expression2.

[Data Types of Operator Results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235255.aspx), Integer Arithmetic :

- **If both operands of a binary operator have the same data type, the result has that data type**. An exception is Boolean, which is forced to Short.
- If an unsigned operand participates with a signed operand, the result has a signed type with at least as large a range as either operand.
- Otherwise, **the result usually has the larger of the two operand data types**.

Comment: So that was it: _"the result is also a byte. But in this case a negative byte which is invalid."_. That makes a lot of sense now, I couldn't see it before. Thank you very much.